# how to create a document in a mongodb collection and update another collection in the same time

Tags: session, mongodb, mongoose

here is my problem

i have three schema

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
        username:String,
        email:String,
        hashed_password:String,
        salt:String,
        shop_id:{type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:'Shop'},
})

var ShopSchema = new Schema({
       owner_id:{type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:'User'},        
       owner_real_id:String,                                    
       owner_real_name:String,                                  
       owner_real_location:String,                              

       shop_name:String,
       sell_product_ids:[Schema.Types.ObjectId],

})

var ProductSchema = new Schema({


})
```

it is necessary to sign up the userschema to use the app, but unnecessary to sign up the shopschema unless the user want to sell some stuff. however when the user do sign up the shopschema i need to update the userschema with the shop's _id,

so here is what i did

1. create the document in shop collection
2. find the shops _id
3. update the user collection

as u can see i query the datebase three times,so i was wondering if this can be done in one query in order to save time like

```
Shop.create(regist_data,function(){
    //update the user collection here
})
```

Just in case u wondering why i need this, its becase i use 'passport' to log user in, and i want to acess the ProductShcema by shop's _id in the req.user, otherwise every time i want to acess the ProductShcema i nend to find the shop's _id and then get the product that belong to the shop's _id.

any way if u have better solution,please let me know.thanx!!!

Answer (score 0):

sorry i think i should've read the mongoose doc more carefully

here is what i figure out

```
Shop.create(regist_data,function(err,shop){
    console.log('shop = '+shop);
    User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.user.id,{ $set: { shop_id: shop._id }},{new:true},function(err,data){
  if(err){
    console.log(err)
  }
  console.log('new user = '+data);
 })
})
```

it create the shop document and update the users collection , it works for me.